# PrimeNG datatable column text overlapping with other columns

Tags: angular, primeng

I have implemented datatable excel like filter as per the example given in PrimeNG documentation. To make filter dialog visible I have to provide overflow style attribute as visible as given below

```
<p-column *ngFor="let col of propsTableCols" [field]="col.field" 
[header]="col.header" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in" [sortable]="true"
[style]="{'overflow':'visible'}">
```

Because of 'overflow':'visible' style column text is going beyond column border and overlapping with other columns text. My requirement is to "clip" the text in columns. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

If I give overflow as hidden column text is clipped but the filter dialog is not getting displayed.

Note:
Implementing word wrap as given below is breaking the words in column not to overlap with other columns but I need to clip it as per my requirement

```
.ui-datatable thead th {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the overflow: hidden in the detail rows only. The best solution is to set a css class that affects only the header with the overflow:visible attribute, otherwise it will be inherited to the detail rows as well.
Another possible solution is to remove the style and check what happens